# Onsite with two different companies in the same state, can I ask them to work together on their arrangements?

Tags: interviewing, human-resources, planning

Recently, I have been phone interviewed by two different companies and both went well. The first company invited for onsite immediately and all the arrangements are made last week, the second company told me the decision to invite me for onsite today. Both companies are in the same state, but in different cities with 6-7 hours drive.

Is it a good idea to tell the second company that I have a interview in that area in two weeks? Also, the first company already made arrangements, so is it okay going back to them to change the return arrangements would it be a good idea again?(I wont affect the schedule of the first company, but can ask the HR to contact the second companies HR to make arrangements and share etc etc). Do you guys think its okay? Just to clarify the companies are competitors and giants in the California area and I am in New york.

Comment: I would really appreciate, if somebody answers my question... As you can clearly see, that I still dont have an answer and the recent stage is, I told the second company about the other interview, she said, okay I will talk to admin and get back to you. Now, can I tell the first company about it. I am guessing the news will only reach with in HR and travel agency. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is too localized. A similar situation can come up often with interviewing.

Comment: @howtechstuffworks - As this question is worded this is unlikely to help anyone but you and thus not on topic for this website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not do this at all, with the possible exception that you're really sought-after, and companies take it as a given that you'll have lots of other interviews/offers. On the surface, you're trying to save yourself time, and the companies involved money.

But I don't think it takes a cynical person to believe that you're really trying to let the companies involved know that you're interviewing other places, and you think that this way you get to do it while looking considerate.

Think of it this way: would you want to pay part of the bill to help an employee interview with a competitor (even if you're saving money)? You may not be in America, so your culture may be different, but we'll go to extreme lengths to avoid paying something that might incidentally benefit someone else.

A less cynical, but no less damaging, way to look at it is that you simply lack the experience to fully reason through the economics of the situation. If a company does have the kind of budget constraints where this would be more attractive than a turn-off, do you really want to move to another state to work for them?

On the bright side, at least one of these companies still wants to bring you in for an interview, despite the fact that I think you've misstepped. So take what I said with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I think I sorted it out. I spoke to both the companies and the first company said, we can cancel the return ticket and the second company arranged the flight from the first company's city to theirs and return to my own place. The second company is taking it cool. Do you think I have got anything wrong here?

Comment: Glad you worked it out. Post back with how it went :)

Comment: Hi Amy, I went for the interview and I got the job with the first company and second company is yet to reply back, even after sending two different emails. I really liked the first companies professionalism, where they said, I will hear back from them a week after the interview, irrespective of the result. The second company is yet to reply and its been two weeks after the interview even after two follow up emails from me. Never mind, after attending the interviews, I thought that I would go for the first company and the second companies result does not matter at this time.

Comment: But I felt I had more chance of clearing the second company's interview and I would say the chance are 95/100 and I am just wondering, what went wrong, even though I pretty much answered each and every question.

Answer (score 7):

tell the second company that you're in their area for business anyway at such and such a time, and would it suit them for you to visit them then, saving everyone involved time and money. No need to tell what that business is.

Comment: ^No, they are in different cities, so inorder to change the arrangements, I have to tell the both the companies about the situations, so they share my flight & stay expenses. Infact, the first company already made arrangements, so now, the first company need to cancel the return flight to NY(I assume corporates always book refundable) and  send me in to flight to second one's office, which is 45 min local flight I guess. Hence the only & best way for this to happen is HR of both the companies to communicate and decide on sharing the costs.

Comment: @howtechstuffworks - You should not make either company you have an interview with somebody else. Do not expect either company to pay you to get to the other city. They are not going to share the expenses so don't even ask.  **You shouldn't assume anything, except for one single truth, if you don't use the return flight and cost the company money you won't get the job.**

Comment: I told both the companies and the first company cancelled their return ticket and the second company arranged me to pick up from there and return me back to my place. Do you think anything might have gone wrong. I was just wondering, if I meet the HR of both the company, how should I react?

Comment: @howtechstuffworks - As professional as possible.